# Don't want directory structure with ZipArchive

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to make file download script that collection all the files and download a zip file that has that collection of files not all the directory structure..

i have the file in download/folder1/folder1/filename.extension

here is my PHP codes:

```
if( !extension_loaded('zip') ){
    echo "<script>alert('Error: Please contact to the Server Administrator!');</script>";
    exit;
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if( $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE ){
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $zip->addFile( BASE_PATH.$file_path.'/'.$file, $file );
    }
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Error: problem to create zip file!');</script>";
    exit;
}
```

this code gives me the structure like this:

[image]

it gives the complete path of wamp(including the path director and files) and the files, i just want to add the files not the directory..

Can someone tell me what i missed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time download link comes with the unique download key, i just add the `unique_key` with the name of download.zip file and its working...

```
// $db_secret_key Random Unique Number
$zipname = $db_secret_key."_download.zip";

if( !extension_loaded('zip') ){
     echo "<script>alert('Error: Please contact to the Server Administrator!');</script>";
     exit;
}


$zip = new ZipArchive;
if( $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE ){
     foreach( $files as $file ){
           $zip->addFile( BASE_PATH.$file_path.'/'.$file, $file );
     }
     $zip->close();

     // Force Download
     header("Content-Type: application/zip");
     header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$zipname");
     header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipname)."");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Expires: 0");
     readfile($zipname);
     exit;
} else {
     echo "<script>alert('Error: problem to create zip file!');</script>";
     exit;
}
```